# Question about the usage of ーたり

Tags: conjugations

I have a question about this construction: (This is from NHK Easy news)

https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011625431000/k10011625431000.html

> 寝る時間が足りないと、心の病気になったり、太りすぎたり、血圧が高くなったりする心配があります.

I want to know the use of "ーたり" in this sentence. Is this a conjugation of some sort if you are listing items? Also, in 高くなったりする, why did it become たりする？

Insights welcome

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55494/multiple-actions-～たり-～たり-する

Comment: Try searching "たり things like" in Google. There are lots of sites that explain this.

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4793/9831

Comment: Don't we have an answer that explains grammar of たり? The linked post doesn't contain information, say, how to conjugate to it etc.

Comment: @bro ^ これとか・・・？　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/60313/9831

Answer (score 1):

According to "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar", page 458:

～たり～たりする
A phrase which expresses an inexhaustive listing of actions or states.

Example:
私達は歌ったり、踊ったりした。
We did things like singing and dancing.